# In the T/Z/F/Chi sq test, are we looking at the Distribution of the Control dataset or Treatment dataset?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions

Pretty straight forward question.

Even if we are looking at the shape of the sample's distribution, are we sampling from the Control group or the Treatment group, or both?

Comment: What is a "T/F/Z test"??

Comment: The standard statistical tests: t test, f test, z test, chi squared test. All of them assume an underlying distribution. But is this distribution assumed for the Control (H0) or Treatment (H1) set?

Comment: None of them assume a specific distribution for the *data.*  They all approximate the *sampling distribution of a test statistic.*  That is possible only when probability assertions can be made about all the data on which the statistic depends, not just part of them.  It is, however, confusing to refer to a bunch of tests as if they were a single test that nobody has ever heard of.  Your question would be better phrased by naming all the tests separately.

Comment: posted as a narrowed down question! https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/603041/in-a-t-test-how-do-we-determine-the-t-statistic-s-distribution-if-we-only-have

Comment: If you're referring to the assumed distribution under which the null distribution of the test statistic is obtained, the assumptions would relate to both the control and treatment groups. However, it's an assumption under the null, and you can get an approximately-correct test size even if the distributional assumption is not correct. In a very wide set of circumstances, with sufficiently-large samples, t-statistics will be approximately t-distributed for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are looking at the distribution of the test statistic.

For instance, in a t-test, we have some parameter we estimate, and we calculate the deviation of the observed parameter from the hypothesized parameter. Then we divide by the standard error. In a two-sample test, that parameter is the difference in means between the control and treatment groups.

When we look at the distributions of the original data, it is to see how well the test statistic will follow the assumed distribution. For instance, in a t-test, the test statistic has the claimed t-distribution when the control and treatment groups are normal. If either group is not normal, then we get a deviation from that claimed t-distribution. Fortunately, the t-test tends to be robust to many violations of this normality assumption (though there might be better approaches, depending on how bad the violation is, and many tests (such as an F-test to compare two variances) have terrible robustness).

Comment: OK, if im understanding correctly, let me check the appropriate steps with you: 1) look at Control group's distribution (lets say its normal) 2) look at Treatment group's distribution (lets say its log normal) 3) pick a test (lets use a T test) 4) calculate the T Statistic 5) repeat the test 100 times to get the T statistic 100 times 6) see if the T statistic's distribution matches the Treatment or Control group's distribution. in this case, if the T stat's distribution is log normal, we may have statistical significance. If the T stat's distribution is normal, then not stat sig?

Comment: @Katsu I am not sure how you got to that from my post. You only have to examine the data sets. The distribution of the test statistic is harder to view, since you use all of your data to calculate one test statistic. If you want to use some kind of bootstrap approach to resample your data and create a mock distribution of your calculated test statistics, that could be reasonable, but you have to do more than just look at graphs, and this is not the way most people do it. (Whether or not people should do it this way is another matter.) // Why calculate 100 test statistics in your approach?

Comment: I wanted to create a distribution of the test statistic n times, and just used n=100 as the placeholder for n. So if not that way, what is the correct step in determining the distribution of the test statistic? Basically im here: 1) look at Control group's distribution (lets say its normal) 2) look at Treatment group's distribution (lets say its log normal) 3) pick a test (lets use a T test) 4) calculate 1 T Statistic 5) determine the single T statistic's distribution (how?)

Comment: @Katsu That’s really a (good) separate question that warrants a full answer instead of just a comment.

Comment: posted! https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/603041/in-a-t-test-how-do-we-determine-the-t-statistic-s-distribution-if-we-only-have