# The T Test requires a Normal distribution for the test to be run. Normal distribution of what?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

**Edited for clarification:**

I'm referring to the beginning of the hypothesis testing process where we are deciding "Which Test should I use, the T test, Z test, F test, or Chi Squared Test?"

The following cheat sheet does a great job in explaining which test you should use, except for the "Distribution" column:

[image]

What is the Distribution column referring to in the context of picking which test to use? Is it referring to the distribution of:

- the Control dataset?
- the Treatment dataset?
- the T statistic (which doesn't make sense cuz its only one number)?

And for bonus:

What do you do if you want to run a T test that suffices all the criteria in the cheat sheet, except the [Control dataset, Treatment dataset, T statistic] **isn't** a normal distribution - what would you do then?

Comment: This does not describe standard testing.  That will make it difficult to answer: should we address the misconceptions or guess at what you are really trying to ask?  The distributional question (5) is standard textbook fare, which means you should easily find it either here or in other resources without much trouble.

Comment: There's certainly missing context here. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Rewrote entire question, hopefully this makes more sense now?

Comment: this graphic is extremely confusing: if it's talking about the distribution of the data, the whole point of z-statistics is we don't have to assume normality of the data. If it's referring to the distribution of the test statistic, this is clearly not the case for t or f statistics. And what the heck does it mean that Any distribution is written next to $\chi^2$? In short: I'm now more confused than you are.

Comment: Heres the source, not as reputable as i would like but all other explanations have been more confusing: https://medium.com/@marin892/test-statistic-cheat-sheet-z-t-f-and-chi-squared-58f4d9db5b99

Comment: let's leave aside this hopelessly confused graphic for now. The t-test assumes normality of the control and test datasets.

Comment: I just noticed that under Test Question, Z test says "do these two populations differ?" while t-test says "Do these two samples differ?". So perhaps best to forget anything you read in that medium article.

Comment: @JohnMadden Awesome thank you for that answer. And what would you do if the t test satisfies all requirements except one of the two datasets are not normally distributed (eg. test dataset is not normally distributed)? Would you use a different test? Would you log transform the test dataset?

Comment: you could either 1) use a nonparametric test or 2) perform a suitable transformation; sometimes this will be a log transform

Comment: Awesome, exactly what i was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Some people would do as @John suggests (I have done it), while others might protest vigorously that such an approach degrades the p-values, *etc.*, and they would be correct, especially for small datasets.  Thus, how you proceed depends on the circumstances and the data.  Many specific variations of this question have been posed here on CV, so consider searching them out for examples and ideas.  In the meantime, if you have a specific problem, then please describe it.

Comment: @whuber I've often wondered about this, do you have any sources you can recommend on this topic? [of the influence of data transformations on type 1 error rates]

Comment: @John There's been plenty of discussion in various circles.  I haven't seen anything definitive, partly because it depends on so many things, such as whether you retain the option of a transformation in your data analysis plan before reviewing the data or, inspired by your initial data review, suddenly realize a transformation would help.  The latter is much harder to account for, especially because you're probably making many other decisions on the fly that might affect your p value, too.